# InvalidNumber File Import Errors when using "number" field type

Tags: marketing-cloud, fileupload, data-import, number

I set up a daily automation to pull in a file import from an SFTP folder. For some reason, Marketing Cloud will not accept the columns as a "number" data type. We rounded the numbers to integers in our query so the file does not have any decimals. None of those fields get close to the limit (An integer, between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,648). If we insert the columns as "Text", they all upload properly.

The issue is that need the columns to insert as numbers in order to use "greater than", "between", "less than" type rules in Journey Builder. I've been back and forth with support for almost a month at this point. They can't give me any recommendations outside of uploading them in as text. I tried inserting them one-by-one to locate if one column in particular is driving the error, but there is no commonality between the ones that fail and the ones that load.

Is there a limit to how many columns can be loaded in as "number"? Anyone else have a similar issue? Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but have you checked if there are any extra spaces in the values that don't load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright finally figured out the issue! Marketing Cloud was importing my file's numbers as decimals (Example: file contained "1209" but would import in as "1209.0"). However, not all of the fields were importing this way. Some of the fields would stay integers. Once I distinguished the ones that were importing in as decimals, I loaded them in as a decimal field type (8,2) and it worked. That still allowed me to use the right rules in Journey Builder. Not sure why exactly it was doing this, but at least it's fixed.